# Agregar un elemento al inicio de un arreglo. En C

Tags: array, c, funciones, modulos

Tengo que hacer una función que agregue un elemento de tipo int al inicio de un arreglo. Intenté con recorrer el contenido del arreglo con un for, y modificar de posición cada uno de los elementos , y así esperando que la posición [0] del arreglo quedase vacía, y ahí poder introducir el nuevo valor. Este es el código:

```
void agregarAlInicio(int arregloGenerado [MAX_ARREGLO], int arregloGeneradoVirgen [MAX_ARREGLO])
{
    int i;
    int agregar = 7;
    for (i = MAX_ARREGLO; i <= 1; i--)
    {
       arregloGenerado[i] = arregloGenerado [i-1];
    }
    arregloGenerado[0] = agregar;
    printf("\n%d agregado al inicio del arreglo: ", agregar);
```

Sin embargo, por lo visto los elementos del arreglo no cambian de valor, ya que el primero de los elementos se ve remplazado, por el valor de la variable *agregar* (7 en este caso)

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Saludos.  Prueba con for (i = MAX_ARREGLO; i >= 1; i--)

Comment: No sabés lo que te agradezco. Estuve todo el día literalmente con este error que no podía avanzar, es increíble como algo tan pequeño, puede causar semejante dolor de cabeza. No sé como marcar que es la respuesta correcta

Comment: @JuanPabloFrersCampos Los comentarios no se pueden marcar como la "correcta". Debe publicarlo como una *respuesta*..

Answer (score 0):

mira pongamos el siguiente caso, tienes la posición A que la quieres mover a la posición B, pero si mueves la posición A a la B, como te está pasando a ti, pierdes la referencia de B porque fue reemplazada.

Entonces lo que debes hacer es guardar B en otra variable un AUX, entonces lo primero es

```
AUX = B
B = A
A = AUX
```

y de está forma no pierdes esa referencia y la guardas en una variable auxiliar.

saludos

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que pones la comprobación contraria a la que debes, por lo que nunca entra al bucle. Aquí:

```
for (i = MAX_ARREGLO; i <= 1; i--)
```

La variable `i` va a tener el valor `MAX_ARREGLO`, que es mayor que 1, por lo que la condición `i <= 1` (menor o igual a 1) es falsa, y el bucle no se ejecutará.

La condición estaría bien si recorrieras de principio a fin, pero al hacerlo del revés, debes poner la condición contraria, es decir, que se ejecute el bucle mientras que la variable `i` sea mayor que `0`.

Una última nota: en un vector de tamaño `N`, los índices van de `0` a `N - 1`, por lo que si intentas ejecutar el bucle va a saltar una violación de segmento, porque estás intentando acceder a `arregloGenerado[MAX_ARREGLO]`, que no existe, porque el último índice es `MAX_ARREGLO - 1`.

Para solucionarlo solo debes cambiar la inicialización del bucle, que quedaría finalmente así.

```
for (i = MAX_ARREGLO - 1; i > 0; i--)
```